# What does the code keyword in Ghidra mean?

Tags: ghidra, decompiler

I'm reversing a binary and I found this strange keyword I haven't seen before  called 'code'. I looked up the C++ keywords and there doesn't seem to be one. Could anyone provide me with more information about this keyword?

```
      if (*(int *)(param_1 + 4) != 0) {
        (*(code *)(&PTR_thunk_FUN_005a7840_008dd8b8)[(int)param_2[4]])(*(int *)(param_1 + 4));
      }
```

In Assembly.

```
00491b95 85  c0           TEST       EAX ,EAX
00491b97 74  10           JZ         LAB_00491ba9
00491b99 8b  4e  10       MOV        ECX ,dword ptr [ESI  + 0x10 ]
00491b9c 8b  14  8d       MOV        EDX ,dword ptr [ECX *0x4  + -> thunk_FUN_005a7840 ] = 00401c30
         b8  d8  8d 
         00
00491ba3 50              PUSH       EAX
00491ba4 ff  d2           CALL       EDX
```

Comment: Not an answer, because I did no diligent research, but I assume that "code*" is supposed to mean "a function pointer of unspecified type", just like "void*" means "a data pointer of unspecified type".

Comment: I see what you're getting at and it does seem like it, but I want more info on it.

Comment: (I'm not totally sure about this to post it as an answer). The decompiler concluded that there is a `CALL` to the address pointed to by your code. It doesn't know its prototype but it does know that this is called as a function. You can't normally `CALL` a `void *`, so `code *` is the way to show it. Consider it a cast to unknown-prototyped function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There was a function rabbit-hole that I was following in Ghidra that had the `(**(code **))` as well.

I cross-examined that section in x64dbg and stepped-over the execution and monitored the EAX register to see the result of `return uVar3;` or `return *(undefined4 *)(iVar2 + 0x2c);`

The result of this (**(code **)) function was a function pointer (0x040E2B98) which contained a function pointer (0x03DE2D10) which contained a function pointer (0x03B2802B) which FINALLY was an actual function that began with `push esi`.

Thus, the answer to this question is...

***`(code *)` is the same as `(void *)`

aka - function pointer

aka - the address location of the beginning of a function

aka - read this [MSDN VOID PTR DOCUMENTATION](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/void-cpp?view=msvc-170)***

```
...
  if ((iVar2 != 0) && (*(int *)(iVar2 + 0x40) != 0)) {
    uVar3 = (**(code **)(*(int *)(*(int *)(iVar2 + 0x40) + 0x28) + 0xc70))();
    return uVar3;
  }
  iVar2 = FUN_03b03811();
  if (iVar2 == 0) {
    return 0;
  }
  return *(undefined4 *)(iVar2 + 0x2c);
```